# error: invalid operands of types ‘double()’ and ‘double()’ to binary ‘operator+’

Tags: c++

Getting the error

> "error: invalid operands of types ‘double()’ and ‘double()’ to binary
>   ‘operator+’
>          + getActualTitheOfferings + getActualLivingExpenses."

when attempting to compile.

Failing to understand what the problem is, including a small segment of code below but can add more if needed to help solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated!

```
/**********************************************************************                                                                  
* Get the difference                                                                                                                    
**********************************************************************/
double actualDifference()
{
    double actualDifference = getIncome - (getActualTaxesWithheld
       + getActualTitheOfferings + getActualLivingExpenses
                                           + getActualOtherExpenses);
}
/**********************************************************************                                                                  
* Display all the variables                                                                                                             
**********************************************************************/
int getDisplay()
{
    double income = getIncome();
    double budgetedLivingExpenses = getBudgetedLiving();
    double actualLivingExpenses = getActualLivingExpenses();
    double actualTaxesWithheld = getActualTaxesWithheld();
    double actualTitheOfferings = getActualTitheOfferings();
    double actualOtherExpenses = getActualOtherExpenses();
    double actualDifference;
    double zero = 0;
```

Comment: Looks like you are confusing a function name with a function call.  For example `getIncome` is an identifier which refers to the function (and I think technically, for portability, one should take the address of it `&getIncome` rather than rely on some sort of conversion to the address).  But `getIncome()` is a function call to that function, and will use the result of the function in the context of the call.

Comment: Your `actualDifference()` function does nothing. It creates a local variable and then forgets about it. Instead of `double actualDifference = ...` its body should be `return ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code attempts to add together two functions. What you means to do was to call the functions and add their results.

The error message tells you this. It says that operator+ does not expect the types 'double()' and 'double()'. 'double()' means a function that takes no parameters and returns a double.

The corrected code would be:

```
double actualDifference = getIncome() - (getActualTaxesWithheld()
       + getActualTitheOfferings() + getActualLivingExpenses()
                                           + getActualOtherExpenses());
```

Comment: I edited the code to what you suggested above and now get the error "error: invalid operands of types ‘double()’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator-’
                                           + getActualOtherExpenses());"                                                The only change in the error I'm seeing is a (-) where there was a (+) after 'operator'

Comment: Right, getIncome() is a function call as well. Edited that in.

Comment: More importantly, is the explanation understandable? You understand that adding together the functions doesn't make sense, you need to call them and then add the results?